# Use MongoDB with Play 2 Framework

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0

I try to find a tutorial who explain me how to implement MongoDB in my Play project (with scala) but apart [Play tips](http://www.playframework.com/modules/mongo-1.1/home) who doesn't help me...

Have you a good site who can help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is such site: [Typesafe Activator / Templates](http://typesafe.com/activator/templates)

There are 2 templates with Reactive Mongo: [1](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/play-mongo-knockout), [2](http://typesafe.com/activator/template/activator-play-autosource-reactivemongo).