# Resquest MongoDB with scala

Tags: mongodb, scala, playframework-2.0, reactivemongo

I want to do an application in `Scala`, with a `MongoDB` database. I found some tutorials to use it with `ReactiveMongo`, I wrote my classes, but I want to test it and I don't understand how to do a simple request; to add a user for example, or find him.

What is the right method to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19118642/298389

Comment: Retrieve documents from the DB with reactive mong drivers : http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.10/documentation/tutorial/find-documents.html

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Activate framework. It supports ReactiveMongo with a simple usage interface for queries and modifications.
Using it, is also easy to switch to other types of databases, like postgre and mysql.

http://activate-framework.org/

It uses transparent persistence with efficient memory usage, providing a simpler persistence paradigm with high scalability. Take a look at http://databen.ch

Comment: That looks great, but how can I install it ? Which dependencies I must put in Build.scala ?

Comment: I work with intelliJ and Play Framework, it doesn't detect the framework, but play has downloaded it... I don't know how to do

Comment: take a look at this example project http://github.com/fwbrasil/activate-example-play.

Comment: and the spray-json documentation: http://activate-framework.org/documentation-v1-3/spray-json-v1-3/

Comment: Can't compile example, it make me a `NoClassDefFoundError: scala/StringContext` error.

Comment: Did you create the eclipse project by calling "sbt eclipse" on the console?

Comment: I use IntelliJ IDEA, so no :) and with this IDE you can create a new Play 2 project without problem...

Answer (score 1):

Do you want ReactiveMongo or just want to use mongodb on scala. If it's the lastest, try http://mongodb.github.io/casbah/tutorial.html

Is what we use in our projects...

Comment: I tried Cabash but my project can't resolve it, so I prefer use Reactivemongo